# Find recipe-ingredient functional dependencies and BCNF decomposition

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I have some problems in finding ALL the correct FDs given a relational schema.
In particular, considering the following database, that stores infomration about user submitted recipes and ingredients:

```
Recipe (userID, code, title, description, username, email, vegan, vegetarian, difficulty)
    with (userID, code) PK
Ingredient (code, name, description, vegan, vegetarian) with (code) PK
RecipeIngredient (userID, recipeCode, ingredientCode, recipeTitle, ingredientName, quantity)
    with (userID, recipeCode, ingredientCode) PK
```

Keys userID, recipeCode in RecipeIngredient are foreign Keys referencing Recipe, and ingredientCode is a foreign key referencing Ingredient. 
Each user has a single email and username. If a recipe or an ingredient are vegan, then they are also vegetarian.

I have to decide if the above database is well designed (meaning in BCNF) and if not, restructure it into BCNF.

How can I find all the FDs?

Comment: What does the reference you were given say what the procedure is? How have you applied it so far? Where are you stuck? PS PKs are irrelvant, candidate keys matter.

Comment: FDs are chosen based on an understanding of the domain and system requirements. Sample data is often useful to see what FDs may hold or don't hold. If all you have is table and column names, I suggest you (a) take the role of data modeler, discuss the system with relevant stakeholders, analyze the requirements and then CHOOSE appropriate FDs, or (b) return the project to its source citing insufficient information.

Comment: Were you *given* those PKs/CKs? Look up the definition of candidate key. When you know columns are a CK, you know certain FDs. That's because it's the FDs that determine the CKs. And so also, if you weren't given those PKs/CKs, why do you think they are CKs?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've tried to find out the following FDs:

code -> code, name, decription, vegan, vegetarian (for the relation "Ingredient", which suggest that Ingredient is in BCNF).

Then:

userID -> email, username

recipe -> title, description, vegan, vegetarian, difficulty

recipeCode -> ingredientCode, ingredientNAme, quantity

Are these correct? Are there other FDs? I can't really find out them. 
Goven the FDs that I've found, can I tell if the DB is in BCNF?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: When we talk about FDs holding it is always with respect to one relation (value or variable). So you need to list FDs for each relation separately. (Similarly, FKs have nothing to do with normalization.) (Also, a FK is from a table & column list to a table & column list.) Please act further on my comment to your question. (If you don't have a definition of FD, how can you find them?) When you think FDs hold or don't hold, say why. Eg "Each user has a single email..."; so in a table holding rows for which "...user U has email E...", all rows with a given U have the same E; so U -> E holds.